# .obj files in Opengl with Textures

Tags: opengl

so I am trying to load a .obj file into a C program using the OpenGL graphics library.  Everything works fine, until I add textures.  Then the image renders in all black and it is barely visible, and only because there is a white axis in the center of the window that is blocked by the object.

I've narrowed it down and I think it has to do with the .mtl file.  If I delete it, the object at least renders in white, normals for lighting, and everything work fine.  There are just no textures.

I have been told to meddle with the .mtl file, double check lighting numbers and such, but I really don't know how to do that or know what reasonable numbers look like.

What exactly is the problem/how do I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a minimal GLUT program demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 3):

OpenGL has no concept of `.obj` or `.mtl`, in fact it has no idea what a file is. You are likely using a separate third party library for this, and your problem likely lies there (or you forgot to add lights and texture coordinates)